# JAX-B Exclude field from output only but allow on input

Tags: java, rest, jersey, moxy, jaxb2

Is there a way to allow a field as input but exclude it from output in JAX-B? I added @XMLTransient, but that prevents the field from being used as an input field. I'm using Jersey 2.25.1 and Moxy.

The scenario is a password field on a user record. I want to allow it to be passed in when creating a new user record, but I don't want to include it in any responses as part of the user POJO.

EDIT:
I tried the @XmlReadOnly attribute and it seems to have done the trick. It is part of the org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations package.

Comment: Put it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use an `XmlAdapter`. You could return the result on the `unmarshal()` and return `null` on the `marhsall()`

```
public class OnlyInputAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String s) throws Exception {
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then just annotate the password property on the model

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OnlyInputAdapter.class)
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}
```

Here's a test

```
public class PasswordSerializationTest extends JerseyTest {

    private User serverUser;

    @Path("test")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public class TestResource {

        @POST
        public User postUser(User user) {
            serverUser = user;
            return user;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig().register(new TestResource());
    }

    @Test
    public void doIt() {
         User clientUser = target("test")
                .request()
                // post string; can't post User as the
                // password field wouldn't serialize
                .post(Entity.json("{\"password\":\"secret\"}"), User.class);

         assertThat(serverUser.getPassword()).isEqualTo("secret");
         assertThat(clientUser.getPassword()).isEqualTo(null);
    }
}
```